# Neo4J Is it possible and how group all nodes with matching property values by that values?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say we had a small document-oriented DB (like ElasticSearch) from which we created our Neo4j DB contents. Each document was about a user depicting its various properties (gender, bank, department, age, position)... I want to visualize all entries in Neo4J, grouping (connecting) users by values of properties that are same. So all 'female' users will be connected as well as all 'Corrosion' department officers. Is it possible and how group all nodes with matching property values by those values?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but do you mean some thing like having a `User` node with a `GENDER` relationship to a `Female` node?  ... etc.?

Comment: @rickg12hs: no I want to do a sort of map/reduce procedure on User properties connecting / grouping all females, males, etc)

Comment: You can just `collect()` your :User nodes by their `gender` property (or whichever properties you're interested in). Are you just asking about how to do this in Cypher, or is this a question on how to visualize the graphical result?

Comment: How to do it in Cypher and to visualize result as a graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To visualize all the `Female` nodes, just run this in the neo4j browser:

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.gender = 'Female'
RETURN n;
```

There is no need to redundantly connect all `Female` nodes together.

In general, this kind of query would execute faster if you also created an appropriate [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/). For example:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(gender);
```

[UPDATE 1]

If you want to see every female `User` who is a member of all clubs, then you could have `MEMBER_OF_CLUB` relationships between `User`s and `Club`s and modify the query accordingly:

```
MATCH (c:Club)
WITH COUNT(c) AS clubCount
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.gender = 'Female' AND SIZE((n)-[:MEMBER_OF_CLUB]->()) = clubCount
RETURN n;
```

This query uses an efficient degreeness operation to check that the number of clubs the `User` belongs to is equal to the total number of clubs.

[UPDATE 2]

To see all the female members of each club (that has any female members), simply use the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT`:

```
MATCH (n:User)-[:MEMBER_OF_CLUB]->(club:Club)
WHERE n.gender = 'Female'
RETURN club, COLLECT(n) AS female_members;
```

[UPDATE 3]

If you really want each `User` node to keep a list of club names (instead of having `Club` nodes and `MEMBER_OF_CLUB` relationships), this should work:

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.gender = 'Female'
UNWIND n.clubs AS club
RETURN club, COLLECT(n) AS female_members;
```

Comment: What to do if I want to see all Females connected as well as all members of `n.club == 'X'` for all different `X` that are in my system?

Comment: I wanted to group by specific clubs different females are in and show it as a graph...

Comment: Will it work if `Club` is not a special object yet just a `User` property?

Comment: If you mean "what if there are no `MEMBER_OF_CLUB` relationships or `Club` nodes, but `User` nodes just have a property containing a list of club names", then that can work too, but the Cypher would be more complex and the execution may be slower. My suggested approach agrees with standard practice.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Could you please provide a code sample for such case?

Comment: I could, but it would be more complex, as I said, and not the recommended approach. So, I would rather not got though the effort of showing you how to do something you should not be doing...

Comment: Yet that was the direct substance of the question I was asking. Please add the sample depicting such case.

Comment: See the new Update 3